# Noise Texture does not work with my mesh

Tags: mesh, texturing, node-editor

I'm new to Blender and following along with the Blender Guru's tutorial series for beginners, where you make a doughnut and coffee. I've been doing everything He does step by step. In Part 4 Level 2 of the series, he adds a Noise Texture. 
In the video it works just fine for him, but when I do it, my mesh (the doughnut) turns pink indicating a problem. I have gone back and retraced my steps several times and I can't figure out what's wrong. I'm using version 2.82.7.

[image]

Can someone please tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Hi, welcome! Blender 2.82a is the latest stable version, released on March 12th, 2020. Your version (2.82.7) seems to be an "experimental" or "custom" one, maybe, but nobody here can know how is different from the stable version, so it is unlikely that anyone can help you with that. Have you tried doing the same with a stable version, than anyone can use to help you? Does it happen even with that?

Comment: @m.ardito *Blender v2.82.7* is the official Windows version from Blender.org. I'm not sure why it's named differently :).

Comment: @JoeBinjimben Hey :). This can have multiple reasons. If you share your file, I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I was just googling the same issue with donut turning up pink and posted about it here and someone very wise informed me Material previews are only in EEVEE and not Cycles: https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/mne2lf/displacement_bumps_not_displaying_properly_while/

I notice you might have the same problem as me - change your top right **Viewport shading** from **Material Preview** to **Rendered**. That is what Andrew had in his tutorial and I simply overlooked it.

it solved the issue for me, hopefully for you too!